# What is the best way to compare two times without a date in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, date, integer

I wanted to know which in your opinion is the best way to compare two different times without a specific date in swift

Currently I have been thinking of implementing this way

```
  static func isClosingTime() -> Bool {
     let currentHour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())
     let currentMinute = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: Date())
     currentHour >= 19 && currentMinute <= 30
  }
```

**I wanted to know if there are better ways**

I accept every suggestion for a clean and correct code

Comment: But what is it you want to compare and how? You say two different times but in your code it looks like you compare one. Is it a specific time or a time interval you want to compare against? Maybe you could add an example in words and numbers as well.

Comment: so here i think there is an english language problem so i apologize but i am using a translator for english and i think it does not translate well ... i just reread my question and actually it is not clear .. sorry but it looks like using a translator is not a good idea .. i try to update my question

Comment: @Joakim Danielson I want the isClosingTime function to return a "True" value when the current time is greater than 19:30 and I wanted to know if my implementation is good or should I use other better ways

Comment: But is this the right question you are asking? In the answer below what happens if the closing time is some time after midnight, say 01:00? Then everything between 01:00 and 23:59 will be after closing time. Also for 19:30 as the closing time this will be unclear since directly after midnight the function will return false so 00:01 is not after closing time.

Comment: in fact I was analyzing just this possibility .. So maybe I should also think about verifying if the current time falls within a time space such as 19:30 - 9:00 or 7pm - 9am.

The function in the answer has already been implemented for other parts of the app but of course I also have to think about your answer so also calculate a time interval

Comment: Yes exactly, you should think of it as an interval where closed is true so to speak.

Comment: Yes, in fact, I'm trying to figure out how to implement this

Comment: One way to handle this in an easier way if you are only working with time is to split it by midnight and check if current time is between closing time and midnight or between midnight and opening time

Comment: Yes I'm only working with time .. What do you mean "split it by midnight?"

Comment: the opening time is 9:00 and the closing time is 19:30

Comment: Divide it into two checks instead of one like I mentioned to make the code logic simpler

Comment: ah so call this function twice? I was trying to create a function that takes two hour into account using the implementation of this answer

Comment: _“...check if current time is between closing time and midnight or between midnight and opening time”_, please read this again since it is the core of what I am trying to say. I will end this discussion now.

Comment: maybe I explained myself badly but that's what I meant .. I'm just trying to figure out how to split the midnight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your explanation it looks like you

> want the isClosingTime function to return a "True" value when the current time is greater than 19:30

Based on that, I can suggest doing this:

- get a closing time as a `Date` object
- compare that closing time date object, to current time

like this:

```
func isClosingTime(hour: Int, minute: Int) -> Bool {

    guard let closingTime = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: hour, minute: minute, second: 0, of: Date()) else {
        return false // could not establish closing time
    }

    return Date() >= closingTime
}
```

You call it as

```
isClosingTime(hour: 19, minute; 30)
```

I will also update the answer for the case you need to handle closing _and_opening time.

```
func shouldBeOpen(from opening: (Int, Int), to closing: (Int, Int)) -> Bool {

    guard let openingTime = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: opening.0, minute: opening.1, second: 0, of: Date()),
          let closingTime = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: closing.0, minute: closing.1, second: 0, of: Date()) else {
        return false // could not establish closing time
    }

    return (openingTime ... closingTime).contains(Date())
}
```

So for example:

```
shouldBeOpen(from: (9, 0), to: (19, 30))
```

The only limitation here is that it works for 1 day, and closing time should be > opening time. But even that can be handled.

Comment: Yes! thanks! 
this seems to be much better

Comment: See my comment above why this solution is not really working.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes it does for the question I answered (read top of the answer). I.e. if you want a closing time for today, it will give it to you exactly. If you want, on top of that, opening time, you can add that too (to the same function even)

Comment: Well you should read my comment above, for instance at 00:01 your method will return false which is a little odd. But that is not important really because the main issue is that the question is wrong.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson depends how you use that function. But I updated the answer to handle both opening and closing time, if that's where OP going to. Yes, it still has a limitation that if you have something opened from 11 PM to 3 AM for example, but in that case you need to get the same logic, just split it to 2 opening/closing intervals, same if you had a break at midday.

Comment: Thank you both for your help with my question .. My question was not complete but unfortunately as I have already said using a translator sometimes I cannot be too clear .. I apologize if I have wasted your time unnecessarily on a wrong question and thank you for the answer which helped me a lot in understanding how to implement this feature